# Apache Tomcat affecting the rendering of pages to IE

Tags: java, apache, internet-explorer, tomcat

I have a Java web app which is working fine on 2 servers I didn't set up (Live and Test).  I set up a new server recently (dev) which is showing some strange issues.  The server is Windows 12 and the app is a maven based java app running in Tomcat with Apache server running on the sever.

If I deploy the application to this server it does not render properly to IE (11).  It works fine but the jsp's and jspf's do not pick up css and oddly do not run conditional comments properly (there is an  comment to display if the version of IE is < 9 and the comment is showing even though not only is the version higher than 9 but it shouldn't even be evaluated in IE 10 or 11 I believe).  The application renders perfectly in Chrome and Firefox.

Has anyone got any idea what could cause this.  I (naively?) thought the same content was sent to all browsers and spent quite a long time looking at the application itself but I'm convinced it has to be an issue on the server now ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this as the first line into your head-section:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
```

Comment: Many thanks this has done the trick.  I'm still completely confused as to why this should be necessary when the app is hosted o one server but not when it is hosted on another mind you.  I guess I can google it when I get a minute though.  Thanks.